# problems with includes for php sites

Tags: php, html

Following problem. I have 2 php files.

```
1.)../folder/main.php
2.)../folder/subfolder/page_coocking.php
3.)../folder/subfolder/bread.php
4.)../folder/subfolder/video_folder/video1.mp4
```

With the following texts in them:

```
1.) main.php
    ..
    include('subfolder/page_coocking.php');
    ..
2.) page_coocking.php
    ..
    include('bread.php');
    ..
3.) bread.php
    ..
    <video controls poster="video_folder/video1.mp4" width="400" height="">
      <source src="video_folder/video1.mp4"/>
    </video>
```

That's the code that I want and the videos would be shown if I open just the `page_coocking.php`, but the videos would not work if I open the `main.php`. I have to write in the `bread.php`

```
    ..
    <video controls poster="subfolder/videos/Rolade.mp4" width="400" height="">
      <source src="subfolder/video_folder/video1.mp4"/>
    </video>
```

to have access to the videos. Why? Can't explain myself. Maybe other style without include?

Comment: Consider the path constructed in bread.php when it's included from main.php, which has a path and from page_coocking.php which exists in a different folder..  `(.\ + video_folder) != (.\subfolder + video_folder)`

Comment: @enhzflep how can i solve this? =/

Comment: You can either use absolute path or use all the path related to the main.php as master path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help you greatly if you adopted some sort of MVC or front controller.  The approach you are taking is hard to maintain at best.

You also want to be very clear on the difference between php file oriented functions like include and require which work with the filesystem of your server, and "web space" which is relative to the webroot of your web server.

You are doing both in this situation, in that you are running scripts directly using web space AND you are including php scripts which has nothing to do with the webroot.

Your problem is that your webroot is 'folder'.  So for anything requested by from the webserver in a url, like for example, main.php the url is http://yourserver.tld/main.php

In main.php if you emit code that then asks the browser to find something relative to it, the relative path is:  `http://yourserver.tld/video_folder/video1.mp4`

This doesn't work of course, because the video is actually in `http://yourserver.tld/subfolder/video_folder/video1.mp4`

Relative webroots do have the concept of a current directory, so when you execute a script in `subfolder` as with bread.php, the webpath at that point is:

`http://yourserver.tld/subfolder/`  because you are executing `http://yourserver.tld/subfolder/bread.php`.  When bread.php emits a relative path, this gets translated to  `http://yourserver.tld/subfolder/video_folder/video1.mp4`.

Frameworks adopt the practice of having a webroot file that is seperate from the php script source.  Only the assets needed to be returned directly from webspace (.css, .js, images) are kept in that directory structure.  There will be a front controller script (typically just index.php) through which all requests are passed, and the front controller can then include other scripts as needed by routing.

Even with your simplified main.php, you could adopt this practice by moving other scripts into a directory so that your file structure would be more like:

```
/project
        /web  (set as webroot for http server, only index.php here)
        /web/js
        /web/css
        /web/images
        /web/videos
        /include (php includes and classes)
```

In your index.php(main.php) you can set constants or variables that will handle all your relative paths.

Comment: its an little bit bad, because i want an combination of more projects and not only one page. thats an problem. i thought the page where i include play as the tunnel in tunnel effect (like the ssh wher i open also an ssh to an other server, where the ssh make the correct interpretation for me). i thougt i could reach the page, in that sence, that bread.php would be connected directly over that tunnel in tunnel form, just with the option that the main.php handle the rest over that include function for intern links so that i see just the normal url of main.php.

Comment: It may help the OP of you could illustrate or *fill out* what an MVC actually is - just saying to some one "you need to use this" gives them very little to actually go forward on, instead say "You need to use A or B or C which are all good types of **thing** [MVC]". Then people can explore Googling (or Binging) how to use MVC A or *MVC B* etc.

Comment: @EduardTester To answer your question, you can have any number of pages you want using a front controller.  This requires some code that looks at the request being made and then branches or includes handling code.  I also mentioned MVC (Model - VIew - Controller) pattern and this is basically what the controller does -- handle routing of requests and figuring out what logic to execute based on the requested url.  The simple way to start with something like this is to use a url parameter named 'page'.  So you might have a 'contact' page, and you would route to that using site.com?page=contact